# Biblatex doesn't recognise a co-author as the same individual as a sole author

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using Biblatex with Biber as follows:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,babel=hyphen,mincrossrefs=3,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

My problem is that where I have an author (Cummins) who has published by himself and also with other authors, it doesn't recognise that this prolifically publishing Cummins is the same person, and provides the initials to supposedly differentiate him.

So, what I want is:

> The concern of this chapter is in the realm of subjective wellbeing based on the Australian Unity Wellbeing Index (Cummins, Eckersley et al. 2003; Cummins 2007a) ... but also for minority groups, and those with disabilities and disdvantageous life circumstances (Foroughi, Misajon and Cummins 2001)...by psychological devices (Cummins 1998; Cummins and Nistico 2002).

But what I am getting is:

> The concern of this chapter is in the realm of subjective wellbeing based on the Australian Unity Wellbeing Index (R. A. Cummins, Eckersley et al. 2003; R. A. Cummins 2007a) ... but also for minority groups, and those with disabilities and disdvantageous life circumstances (Foroughi, Misajon and R. Cummins 2001)...by psychological devices (R. A. Cummins 1998; R. A. Cummins and Nistico 2002).

Is there a way I can indicate with a field or something to Biblatex that the Cummins entries in question, are all for the same person?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hmmm... I am having trouble replicating my issue in a MWE.  Will endeavour to provide one.

Comment: Ahhhh I have discovered the problem. One of the citations with this co-author had simply the initials rather than the full name as it has appeared in all the other citations. By changing it to the same format, I've resolved the problem. Apologies for wasting anyone's time.

Comment: Since there is an answer that obviously solves your problem, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows that the answer helped you, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: huge apologies (I'm new) will do now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biber` uses [hash funcions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to distinguish between authors. To be identified as the same author, the name has to be written *exactly* the same in both cases to produce the same hash. If you enter the name once with full first name and once with initials only, it will not produce the same hash and `biber` or `biblatex` will treat it as two different persons.

Comment: Thanks Benedikt - that makes sense. I had replicated what the author had put when they published (two different renderings of their name), but I'm going to make them all the same full named author so that they aren't incorrectly differentiated as "Robert A. Cummins" and "Robert Cummins".